# How to access an "internal variable" from an object in Java?

Tags: java, oop, variables

I was wondering how I could access an internal variable from an object in Java (a variable declared after construction). I experimented with the following code:

```
public class test1 {
    public test1(int bigNumber, int smallNumber) {

        int result = bigNumber - smallNumber;

    }
}

class invoke {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test1 t1 = new test1(10, 5);
        System.out.println(t1.result); //this was an invalid statement

    }

}
```

In the code, the statement

```
System.out.println(t1.result);
```

was invalid. Why can I not retrieve the internal state of the object? Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` is currently a local variable which is only visible to the scope of the containing method. Instead, make `result` an instance variable.

Example:

```
class test1 {
    int result;
    public test1(int bigNumber, int smallNumber) {
        result = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is not defined in the scope of the `test1` instance.
It is defined in the scope of the `test1` constructor.
To be able to access a variable inside a method or a constructor, that has to be defined as a field and you should also provide a method to access it (to allow it to be a `private` field) such as  :

```
public class test1 {
    private int result;
    public test1(int bigNumber, int smallNumber) {
       result = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    }
    public int getResult(){  
      return result;
    }
}
```

You can know access to `result` in this way :

```
test1 t1 = new test1(10, 5);
System.out.println(t1.getResult());
```

Note that `test1`  doesn't respect java naming conventions.
Class names have to start with an uppercase : `Test1` is better.